# what is the latex command for this notation

Tags: math-mode, matrices

could anyone tell me what will be the latex command for this? I am very much confused, I am not even comfortable in matrix writing while typing latex I always copy paste the matrix command to write a matrix as I can not remember. thank u for helping[image: C]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I offer three variants, all of them are fine IMHO, and which one you choose depends only on your preferences somehow:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{pmatrix}
    \varphi\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
  &
    \varphi\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
  \\
    \varphi\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
  &
    \varphi\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
  \end{pmatrix}
\]
\[
  \begin{pmatrix}
    \varphi\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
  &
    \varphi\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
  \\[2ex]
    \varphi\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
  &
    \varphi\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
  \end{pmatrix}
\]
\[
  \begin{pmatrix}
    \varphi\begin{psmallmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{psmallmatrix}
  &
    \varphi\begin{psmallmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{psmallmatrix}
  \\[1ex]
    \varphi\begin{psmallmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{psmallmatrix}
  &
    \varphi\begin{psmallmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{psmallmatrix}
  \end{pmatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: By four seconds, I was going to post mine :)

Comment: @Manuel Well, writing code directly here helps :)

Comment: I was doing so. Just when I ended, a killing `1 new answer to this question` line appeared, clicked on it and said “4 seconds ago”.

Comment: You may want to add `[2ex]` of extra vertical space after the first interior row so that the parentheses of two matrices in the first row don't tangle with the parentheses of the next two matrices.

Comment: @Mico thanks for the suggestion. I actually included yet another version :)